# Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, poo

Hice una clase en esta ubicación *app/Libs/* para conectarme y utilizar Firestore con Laravel.

```
namespace app\Libs;

use Exception;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;


class Firestore
{


    private $db;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $collection)
    {
        $this->db = new FirestoreClient([
            'projectID' => 'mi_coleccion',
            'keyFilePath' =>  'Firebase.json'
        ]);

        $this->name = $collection;
    }

    public static function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
```

Esta clase la voy a instanciar en un controller llamado FirestoreController con el siguiente código

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libs\Firestore;


class FirestoreController extends Controller
{

    public function firestoreTest()
    {
        $fs = new Firestore('rides_current');
        $fs->getConnection();
    }

}
```

cuando entro por método get a la función firestoreTest me arroja el siguiente error, cabe señalar que ya hice una conexión satisfactoria en otro script de php sin ningún framework y puedo hacerlo sin problema, agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías checar el método estático `getConnection()` por ahi parece ir el problema, te recomiendo leer aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 0):

Tu método `public static function getConnection()` es de tipo estático por lo tanto no es válido que trates de acceder a una propiedad de la clase con la sintaxis de:

```
$this->propiedad
```

De lo anterior, podemos revisar la documentación de PHP<sup>1</sup> que al respecto nos dice:

> Debido a que los métodos estáticos se pueden invocar sin tener creada una instancia del objeto, la seudovariable $this no está disponible dentro de los métodos declarados como estáticos.

Entonces puedes por ejemplo:

- Declarar a la propiedad `$db` como estática de este modo:

  ```
    private static $db;
  ```
- De modo que cuando la invoques dentro del método estático lo hagas así:

  ```
    pubic static function getConnection()
    {
        return self::$db;
    }
  ```

Anexo a lo anterior, **para acceder al método esático no es necesario construir una instancia de la clase**, basta acceder al método por medio del [operador de resolución de ámbito](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php#language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim) mas o menos así:

```
Clase::metodoNombre();
```

Donde me parece que tu código pudiera quedar así:

```
$fs = new Firestore('rides_current');
Firestore::getConnection(); /*Aqui no requerimos del objeto instanciado*/
```

Por otro lado no se que tanta apertura tengas de modificar la declaración del método, lo digo por que simplemente podrías quitarle el `static` y entonces si acceder a la propiedad como lo intentas con la *pseudovariable* `$this->`

```
    private $db;

    pubic function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
```

Pero lo anterior depende de que el cambio sea posible en función de no afectar otras funcionalidades dependientes de la estructura original.

**Referencia**

- [Métodos estáticos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods)